# php как вывести все данные массива

Tags: php

Как можно вывести все данные из такого массива кроме данных с именем index.php?
Вариант с $list[0] не подходит т.к данные массива будут дополняться

```
Array ( [0] => 4.png [1] => bot.zip [2] => g2ldr [3] => index.php )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $arr = array("4.png", "bot.zip", "g2ldr", "index.php");
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($value) {
    return $value != "index.php";
});
print_r($arr);
```

Если нужно вывести , только имена файлов , то можно использовать цикл
foreach

```
$list = array("4.png", "bot.zip", "g2ldr", "index.php");

foreach ($list as $item) {
  if ($item !== "index.php") {
    echo basename($item) . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Мне нужно без всяких Array ( [0] а только имя файлов 4.png и т.д